# Regular expression in powershell to replace complete XML node with empty value

Tags: .net, powershell

This is my web.config file and content.

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

This is my power shell script to remove everything from the tag ...

```
(Get-Content C:\Temp\web.config) | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '<dependentAssembly>[\s\S]*?<\/dependentAssembly>', ''} | 
Set-Content C:\Temp\web.config
```

Script is running but its not removing anything. Can anyone please help me in this. What the mistake i am making in above code.

Expected output:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us what you expect the file to look like afterwards as well?

Comment: Added my expected output.

Comment: David already provided the only correct answer but you **do have to read** [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/52598). In short, regex is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I want to do that with regular expression only. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions for doing that. PowerShell offers you all what you need to deal with XML.

```
$xml = [xml] @"
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
"@

$xml.runtime.assemblyBinding.RemoveAll()

$xml.Save("c:\temp\test.xml")
```